Trying to remove a Kobalt 80v trimmer head that does NOT have a flathead screw
Can anyone help?  I have an 80v brushless Kobalt trimmer and the bump head finally wore out.  The videos online show a flathead screw holding it on,mine does not.

Hi, and welcome to the site.  Could you please add a few pictures of what your trimmer head looks like?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Its difficult to advise without knowing what you are seeing - but the trimmers that I have seen mostly tend to have a hole in the rotating area between the shaft and the trimmer head.   The general idea is to poke something in the hole (ideally the tool it came with, but a screwdriver or drill bit or similar will do as well - and then slowly rotate the head while pushing the  screwdriver in until it goes further into the whole, locking the spinning mechanism in place.   The head then typically just unscrews with hand pressure.

Very often (but not always) the heads are reverse threade, so if unscrewing it does not work [once the head is locked in place], try turning the opposite direction.
